# How to fix 'An uncaught Exception was encountered' Type: ArgumentCountError

Tags: codeigniter

I Follow this error Message: Too few arguments to function Crud_model::update_course(), 1 passed in D:\OneDrive - Combina Solucoes em Tecnologia Ltda\Sites\senaec.com.br\ead\application\controllers\Admin.php on line 434 and exactly 2 expected

So I pass the 2 arguments on:

In this case the error show when a try access the followin URL: localhost/ead/courses_action/edit/2

```
public function course_actions($param1 = "", $param2 = "") {
        if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != true) {
            redirect(site_url('login'), 'refresh');
        }

        if ($param1 == "add") {
            $this->crud_model->add_course();
            redirect(site_url('admin/courses'), 'refresh');

        }
        elseif ($param1 == "edit") {
            $this->crud_model->update_course($param2);
            redirect(site_url('admin/courses'), 'refresh');

        }
        elseif ($param1 == 'delete') {
            $this->crud_model->delete_course($param2);
            redirect(site_url('admin/courses'), 'refresh');
        }
        elseif ($param1 == 'view_details') {
            $page_data['page_name'] = 'course_details';
            $page_data['page_title'] = get_phrase('course_details');
            $page_data['course_details'] = $this->crud_model->get_course_by_id($param2)->row_array();
            $this->load->view('backend/index', $page_data);
        }
    }
```

Someone can see the error in this case to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that `$param2 = 2`, have you tried echoing it just to make sure? .. cause the error says that `update_course` didn't receive a parameter.

Comment: You are only passing one argument to `update_course` but it requires two. Look carefully. `update_course` not `course_actions`

Answer (score 0):

First follow the rules of url

```
server/projectName/controller/function/param1/param2
```

You have mentioned your url is

```
localhost/ead/courses_action/edit/2
```

If 'course_action' is your function name then where is the controller. Please specify following the url pattern.

Comment: Hi @Mahmudul In this case param1=edit and param2=2.

Looks like this:

`public function update_course($course_id, $type) {
        $outcomes = $this->trim_and_return_json($this->input->post('outcomes'));
        $requirements = $this->trim_and_return_json($this->input->post('requirements'));
        $data['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
        $data['short_description'] = $this->input->post('short_description');
      
        $this->db->where('id', $course_id);
        $this->db->update('course', $data);

        
    }
`